# request.post.get() is empty -- Django

Tags: python, html, django

On my website, the user can type into this form and hit submit:

```
<form action="{% url "reikna" pk=doc.id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        calc_date <input type="text" id="calc_date" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Parts of the view function `reikna()`:

```
def reikna(request):
    calc_date = request.POST.get("calc_date", False)
    f = open('calc_log.txt', 'w')
    f.write(str(calc_date)+'\n')
```

The calc_log.txt file always contains `False`, even though I type something into the form. What am I doing incorrectly? As I understand it, the `id` attribute should be the identifier for the `request.post.get()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`calc_date <input type="text" id="calc_date" />` should be  calc_date `<input type="text" name="calc_date" />`

Comment: Right you are. Thanks.